# SSRS Report Builder Shortcuts

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

Its just a short Question I couldn't find any answers here or in the web thou.
Is there a shortcut to jump into an expression in a Report?

I handle complicated Reports with basicly only expressions and it would be much faster if there where a shortcut to open a Expression in a Textfield.

Thank you in advance
Nicolas

Comment: this isn't a question for StackOverflow and will probably be closed. But I'm not sure how much shorter you can get than `Right-Click Textbox then Click Expression`?

Comment: yeah I know but it is worth a try, that method is sufficient on normal reports but my reports have expressions only and then it would be much faster if there were a shortcut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The report file (.rdl) is actually plain XML. So you can edit the expressions directly in this format. If you are using Visual Studio, right-click on the report and select "View Code" to get the XML editor.

If you are making the same change to multiple expressions you can use the Find & Replace option in the VS code editor. You can also copy and paste cells (textboxes in a table) in the normal visual view. You can even copy and paste multiple cells if needed.